# wtforms app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, model, wtforms

I'm switching to using webapp2 in app engine.

I've used djangoforms before which is unsupported now.

I've tried wtforms, but seems to give me errors:

import

```
 from wtforms.ext.django.orm import model_form
```

model

```
class Systems(db.Model):
 field = db.StringProperty()
```

view

```
SystemsForm = model_form(Systems)
```

error

```
    model_fields = ((f.attname, f) for f in model._meta.fields)
AttributeError: type object 'Systems' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: changed import to app engine version

Comment: from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form